# Как передать срез в функцию в качестве параметра

Tags: python-3.x, срез

Например есть список a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Как передать срез в функцию как параметр?

Например:

```
def foo(param):
    print(a[param])
param = '1:'
foo(param)
```

Понимаю что так нельзя но суть такова

Comment: `param = slice(1, None)`

Comment: foo(a[1:]) не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
def foo(start=0, end=None):
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    print(a[start : end])

start = 1
foo(start)

# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```